# Heroku push failing with error regarding sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I am trying to push to master but it's not working. I used

```
git push heroku master
```

The error I'm getting is

```
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

enter code here

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:jmatharu.git enter code here
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:jmatharu.git'
```

Can anyone help me in this case.

Comment: See [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

Answer (score 3):

That would be because Heroku does not support SQLite.  See [this Heroku Documentation on how to set up your application for PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres), which is pretty clear.

In a nutshell you must pick a PostgreSQL plan and then provision your application to connect to it.  This is mostly just using the `pg` gem rather than SQLite3.

But very soon you will want to run PostgreSQL in your development environment, too.  SQLite and Postgres dialects of SQL differ in many ways.  Setting up Postgres for development can be a bit tedious, particularly for anything other than Linux.  And the exact procedure changes over time.  Your best bet is to Google "Rails Postgresql setup for [your operating system]".

Comment: See also [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).